# LINQ contains and fix

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have a LINQ query

```
var age = new int[]{1,2,3};
dbContext.TA.WHERE(x=> age.Contains( x.age)).ToList()
```

In an online article #11 (https://medium.com/swlh/entity-framework-common-performance-mistakes-cdb8861cf0e7) mentioned it is not a good practice as it creates many execution plan at the SQL server.

In this case, how should LINQ be revised so that I can do the same thing but minimize the amount of execution plans generated?

(note that I have no intention to convert it into a stored procedure and pass & join with the UDT as again it requires too many effort to do so)

Answer (score 0):

That article offers some good things to keep in mind when writing expressions for EF. As a general rule that example is something to keep in mind, not a hard "never do this" kind of rule. It is a warning over writing queries that allow for multi-select and to avoid this when possible as it will be on the more expensive side.

In your example with something like "Ages", having a hard-coded list of values does not cause a problem because every execution uses the same list. (until the app is re-compiled with a new list, or you have code that changes the list for some reason.) Examples where it can be perfectly valid to use this is with something like Statuses where you have a status Enum. If there are a small number of valid statuses that a record can have, then declaring a common array of valid statuses to use in an `Contains` clause is fine:

```
public void DeleteEnquiry(int enquiryId)
{
    var allowedStatuses = new[] { Statuses.Pending, Statuses.InProgress, Statuses.UnderReview };

    var enquiry = context.Enquiries
        .Where(x => x.EnquiryId == enquiryId && allowedStatuses.Contains(x.Status))
        .SingleOrDefault();
    
    try
    {
        if(enquiry != null)
        {
            enquiry.IsActive = false;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            // Enquiry not found or invalid status.
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) { /* handle exception */ }
}
```

The statuses in the list aren't going to change so the execution plan is static for that context.

The problem is where you accept something like a parameter with criteria that include a list for a `Contains` clause.

it is highly unlikely that someone would want to load data where a user could select ages "2, 4, and 6", but rather they would want to select something like: ">=2", or "<=6, or "2>=6"  So rather than creating a method that accepts a list of acceptable ages:

```
public IEnumerable<Children> GetByAges(int[] ages)
{
    return _dbContext.Children.Where(x => ages.Contains( x.Age)).ToList();
}
```

You would probably be better served with ranging the parameters:

```
private IEnumerable<Children> GetByAgeRange(int? minAge = null, int? maxAge = null)
{
    var query = _dbContext.Children.AsQueryable();
    if (minAge.HasValue)
        query = query.Where(x => x.Age >= minAge.Value);
    if (maxAge.HasValue)
        query = query.Where(x => x.Age <= maxAge.Value);
    return query.ToList();
}

private IEnumerable<Children> GetByAge(int age)
{
    return _dbContext.Children.Where(x => x.Age == age).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response and the BI evaluation. But the fact is the age is just an example. In my scenario, the array is not static and vary very frequently/dramatic (the dataset size are from 0 to few thousand). I pretty sure that the arr.Contains(x=>x.value) is matched with the article "Don't" .

Comment: If you are looking for an alternative then update your question with an example that demonstrates exactly what you want to accomplish. If you are populating the array based on user selection then you're probably pretty much stuck with the execution plan cost. If the selection can be done instead based on a Join off another column/criteria then it might be avoidable.  Are you encountering an actual performance issue with your existing query, or merely worried about possibly encountering one in the future?